# Distance to nearest point by group using sf

Tags: r, data.table, distance, r-sf

I have a dataset that looks similar to the example below. For each `code` I would like to calculate the distance to the next nearest code that belongs to the same `area` as it. So in my example, for each code belonging to area A001 I would be after an additional column in the dataset that contains the minimum distance to one of the other points that belong to area A001. I assume there should be a way of using `st_distance` to achieve this?

```
require("data.table")
require("sf")

dt1 <- data.table(
code=c("A00111", "A00112","A00113","A00211","A00212","A00213","A00214","A00311","A00312"),
area=c("A001", "A001","A001","A002","A002","A002","A002","A003","A003"),
x=c(325147,323095,596020,257409,241206,248371,261076,595218,596678),
y=c(286151,284740,335814,079727,084266,078283,062045,333889,337836))

sf1 <- st_as_sf(dt1, coords = c("x","y"), crs=27700, na.fail=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a 'cleaner' way to get here, but this gets you the correct values.

```
library(tidyverse)

# intermediate fun to help later in apply()
smallest_non_zero <- function(x) {
  min_val <- min(x[x != 0])
  x[match(min_val, x)]
}

closest_grp_distances <- sf1 %>%
  group_split(area) %>%
  map(~st_distance(., .) %>% # returns matrix
       apply(1, smallest_non_zero)) %>%
  unlist()

sf1$closest_grp_distances <- closest_grp_distances
```

I wanted to use the baseR `split` but it doesn't have a method for `sf` objects.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: Error in UseMethod("st_geometry") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_geometry' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"

Comment: Hmm, can you tell what step that's happening in? My guess is `st_distance()`. Also a good idea to compare package version, here are mine forcats_0.3.0,     stringr_1.4.0, dplyr_0.8.0.1, purrr_0.3.0, readr_1.3.1, tidyr_0.8.2 , tibble_2.0.1, ggplot2_3.1.0, tidyverse_1.2.1, sf_0.7-3, data.table_1.12.0

Comment: Really there is no need for me to be loading the entire `tidyverse` so really the packs that matters are `sf`, `data.table`, `dplyr` and `purrr`.

Comment: My package versions are: purrr_0.3.0, dplyr_0.8.0.1, data.table_1.12.0, sf_0.7-2. Perhaps something to do with the different versions of sf?

Comment: https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/commit/5594eba6387dbe48836cb1a7b3afc064b78a89de looks like it could be the different sf versions we are using

Comment: yea that's totally what it is. `group_split()` is new as of `dplyr_0.8.0` so that that makes sense that `sf` commit upped the suggested version and added the method.

Comment: Well it looks like today is the day sf 0.7-3 is published. Once I get a chance to update I'll give it a go on my real data.

Comment: good hunting on the difference. I just happened to be re-installing it yesterday to get some new proj4 projections working so it was a happy accident it worked on my machine